# after you have clicked or hovered can you change state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

trying to make an input box do the following: normal sate the input box text is x, hover state the input text is y and was you leave the box its z and can stay z through all states again.

-update
 have a search box which the background image and text are faded out, once you hover it is is vivid, once you focus it, it is vivid with a 2px border, but once you leave it i loose verything:( so need a trick to get it to stay vivid the background picture (of which there are x and y, one for each state) and the text but loose the 2px border

```
---UPDATE ---
/* Search box */
.searchbox {
    background: url(../images/search-grey.gif) no-repeat 6px -5px #f8f8f8;
    width:240px; 
    margin-right:4px; 
    margin-left:11px; 
    color:#cccccc;   
    vertical-align: top; 
    padding: 4px 2px 4px 79px;
    border-color: #4FA4F9;
}
.searchbox:hover {
    background: url(../images/search-greyb.gif) no-repeat 6px -5px #f8f8f8;
    color:#888888; 
}
.searchbox:focus {
    background: url(../images/search-greyb.gif) no-repeat 5px -6px #ffffff;
    width:239px; 
    color:#888888; 
    padding: 3px 2px 3px 78px;
}
.searchbox.blur {
    background: url(../images/search-greyb.gif) no-repeat 6px -5px #ffffff;
    width:239px; 
    color:#000000; 
    padding: 4px 2px 4px 79px;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .searchbox {
    background: url(../images/search-grey.gif) no-repeat 6px -4px #f8f8f8;
    }
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .searchbox:hover {
    background: url(../images/search-greyb.gif) no-repeat 6px -4px #f8f8f8;
        }
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .searchbox:focus {
    background: url(../images/search-greyb.gif) no-repeat 5px -5px #f8f8f8;
    }
}

input::-moz-focus-inner /*Remove button padding in FF*/
{ 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input, select, textarea {
  margin: 1 0 0;
}
input, textarea, .date {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color:#333;
}
input {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0px;
}
textarea {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

select:hover {border: 1px solid #4FA4F9;}
input:hover {border: 1px solid #4FA4F9;}
textarea:hover {border: 1px solid #4FA4F9;}
select:focus {padding: 0px;}
input:focus {padding: 0px;}
textarea:focus {padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;

}
```

--- html ---

```
<input id="searchdomain" name='domain' type="text" style="font-size:15px;" class="searchbox"/>
```

---js----

```
/* Search Box Leave */
$(".searchbox").blur(function(){
    $(this).addClass("blur");
});
```

Comment: Very undetailed what you want. You want the color to be black once data is entered? Then `.searchbox[value!=""]`

Comment: Are you referring to [`mouseenter`/`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)?

Comment: Who knows? This is a true mystery what he wants considering given information.

Comment: try jquery mouseleave, focusout or blur.

Comment: out of curiosity are you trying to mimic the placeholder functionality here? Just looks like it to me ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this using jQuery by setting a class.

```
$(".searchable").blur(function() {
    $(this).addClass("blur");
});
```

Then in your css you can set the color like this

```
.searchable.blur
{
  color:#000;   
}
```

​
Here is a jsfiddle example -> http://jsfiddle.net/y46Wk/2/

Just bear in mind that the element won't show its hover color again unless you remove the class.

Comment: excelent thought it was clear enough we all speak code here lol works a charm. so blur is the function when you leave an element?

Comment: It is yes, this will only work for elements you can focus on though, like input boxes and the like :)

Comment: good man brain upgrade more possibilities, love it thank you sam!

Comment: having trouble with the jquery not sure if its because i have asigned css to "input"?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that would cause a problem. Are you putting the jQuery i wrote inside a document ready?

Comment: @DavidWalter Can you show the section thats causing you trouble in a jsfiddle?

Comment: You need to add some text into the searchbox like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/epZLN/

Comment: @DavidWalter Are you trying to do a placeholder type effect?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14138/discussion-between-sam-and-david-walter)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to your question.... but I have a feeling you're doing some validation on a form, so why not look at a jQuery validation plugin like this
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Here is a list of other form related jQuery stuff
http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/22/50-jquery-plugins-for-form-functionality-validation-security-and-customisation/

If none of them help, perhaps you could tell us which one comes close to give us a bit of a clue as to what you want ;-)

Comment: Not really for validation, just have a search box which the background image and text are faded out, once you hover it is is vivid, once you focus it, it is vivid with a 2px border, but once you leave it i loose verything:( so need a trick to get it to stay vivid the background picture (of which there are x and y, one for each state) and the text but loose the 2px border.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood and +1 for the answer above

Comment: having trouble with the jquery not sure if its because i have asigned css to "input"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/y46Wk/4/

Comment: like the remove class, when it adds a this class does it overide all other classes?

Comment: having trouble with the jquery not sure if its because i have asigned css to "input"?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing (maintaining a state) is technically possible with just CSS.

Here is [an article](http://joelb.me/blog/2012/maintaining-css-style-states-using-infinite-transition-delays/) explaining the process.
In summary you use a transition state, triggered by focus, to keep styles applied to the element. I'm not advocating it as the *best method*, but it is really quite interesting to see what you can do with CSS3 properties.

More of a curiosity than a straight answer but hopefully its helpful to you / others who hit this question :)

Comment: having trouble with the jquery not sure if its because i have asigned css to "input"?